# How to navigate from SKScene to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, viewcontroller

So I'm working on a game whereby if it's game over it takes you back to the main menu. If you complete the level it reloads the GameScene (as per the func switchToNewGameWithTransition) with the new level and the game continues.

The issue I'm having is this: If it goes to game over, I get taken back to the main menu. If I then start the game again and complete a level, the GameScene fails to reload. Well, rather it reloads (I know this from the node count) but when run(SKAction.sequence([delay, sceneChange])) runs in func switchToNewGameWithTransition nothing changes.

There is also about a 20MB rise in memory every time I press start game on the main menu screen after game over is called. Is this due to the way I've structured my code?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    ...

    run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)) {

        self.viewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    ...

    fileprivate func switchToNewGameWithTransition(_ transition: SKTransition) {
    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
    let sceneChange = SKAction.run({

      let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
      self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    })

    run(SKAction.sequence([delay, sceneChange]))
  }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let skView = self.view as! SKView


        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 667))

        scene.scaleMode = .fill

        scene.viewController = self
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```